# How to use and build a makefile to link scip to C?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, scip

I am very new in C. I just need to use one of the functions in scip. I made a make file as below:

```
SCIPDIR=$/Users/amin/Documents/cProgram/scipoptsuite-6.0.2/scip

include $(SCIPDIR)/make/make.project

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OFLAGS) $(BINOFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

all: cmain

cmain: cmain.o
    $(LINKCXX) cmain.o $(LINKCXXSCIPALL) $(LDFLAGS) $(LINKCXX_o) cmain
```

my cmain.c file is like this:

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/*                                                                           */
/*                  This file is part of the program and library             */
/*         SCIP --- Solving Constraint Integer Programs                      */
/*                                                                           */
/*    Copyright (C) 2002-2019 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum                            */
/*                            fuer Informationstechnik Berlin                */
/*                                                                           */
/*  SCIP is distributed under the terms of the ZIB Academic License.         */
/*                                                                           */
/*  You should have received a copy of the ZIB Academic License              */
/*  along with SCIP; see the file COPYING. If not visit scip.zib.de.         */
/*                                                                           */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

/**@file   GMI/src/cmain.c
 * @brief  main file for GMI cut example
 * @author Marc Pfetsch
 */

/*--+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2*/

#include <scip/scip.h>
#include <scip/scipdefplugins.h>

/** reads parameters */
static
SCIP_RETCODE readParams(
   SCIP*                 scip,               /**< SCIP data structure */
   const char*           filename            /**< parameter file name, or NULL */
   )
{
   if ( filename != NULL )
   {
      if ( SCIPfileExists(filename) )
      {
         SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "reading parameter file <%s> ...\n", filename);
         SCIP_CALL( SCIPreadParams(scip, filename) );
      }
      else
         SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "parameter file <%s> not found - using default parameters.\n", filename);
   }
   else if ( SCIPfileExists("scipgmi.set") )
   {
      SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "reading parameter file <scipgmi.set> ...\n");
      SCIP_CALL( SCIPreadParams(scip, "scipgmi.set") );
   }

   return SCIP_OKAY;
}

/** starts SCIP */
static
SCIP_RETCODE fromCommandLine(
   SCIP*                 scip,               /**< SCIP data structure */
   const char*           filename            /**< input file name */
   )
{
   /********************
    * Problem Creation *
    ********************/

   SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "read problem <%s> ...\n\n", filename);
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPreadProb(scip, filename, NULL) );

   /*******************
    * Problem Solving *
    *******************/

   /* solve problem */
   SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "solve problem ...\n\n");
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPsolve(scip) );

   SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "primal solution:\n");
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPprintBestSol(scip, NULL, FALSE) );

   /**************
    * Statistics *
    **************/

   SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "Statistics:\n");
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPprintStatistics(scip, NULL) );

   return SCIP_OKAY;
}

/** starts user interactive mode */
static
SCIP_RETCODE interactive(
   SCIP*                 scip                /**< SCIP data structure */
   )
{
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPstartInteraction(scip) );

   return SCIP_OKAY;
}

/** creates a SCIP instance with default plugins, evaluates command line parameters, runs SCIP appropriately,
 *  and frees the SCIP instance
 */
static
SCIP_RETCODE runSCIP(
   int                   argc,               /**< number of shell parameters */
   char**                argv                /**< array with shell parameters */
   )
{
   SCIP* scip = NULL;

   /*********
    * Setup *
    *********/

   /* initialize SCIP */
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPcreate(&scip) );

   /* we explicitly enable the use of a debug solution for this main SCIP instance */
   SCIPenableDebugSol(scip);

   /***********************
    * Version information *
    ***********************/

   SCIPprintVersion(scip, NULL);
   SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "\n");

   /* include default SCIP plugins */
   SCIP_CALL( SCIPincludeDefaultPlugins(scip) );

   /**************
    * Parameters *
    **************/

   if ( argc >= 3 )
   {
      SCIP_CALL( readParams(scip, argv[2]) );
   }
   else
   {
      SCIP_CALL( readParams(scip, NULL) );
   }

   /**************
    * Start SCIP *
    **************/

   if ( argc >= 2 )
   {
      SCIP_CALL( fromCommandLine(scip, argv[1]) );
   }
   else
   {
      SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "\n");

      SCIP_CALL( interactive(scip) );
   }

   /********************
    * Deinitialization *
    ********************/

   SCIP_CALL( SCIPfree(&scip) );

   BMScheckEmptyMemory();

   return SCIP_OKAY;
}

/** main method starting SCIP */
int main(
   int                   argc,               /**< number of arguments from the shell */
   char**                argv                /**< array of shell arguments */
   )
{
   SCIP_RETCODE retcode;

   retcode = runSCIP(argc, argv);
   if ( retcode != SCIP_OKAY )
   {
      SCIPprintError(retcode);
      return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Now in the directory that I have these 2 file, I run Make but it doesn't work I get error: `No such file or directory`

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Users/amin/Documents/cProgram/scipoptsuite-6.0.2/scip/make/make.project'.  Stop.
```

I just tried to follow a instruction that someone suggested. Please help me if you can. what I have to do?

Comment: What is the name of the makefile?  What command line did you use to invoke make?  Please post the full resulting output.

Comment: name is Makefile, and in the directory that Makefile and cmain.c exist I just use command : make

Comment: [Edit] your post. State explicitly what you did, and show the full results.

Comment: I put the whole things that I got after running make

Comment: I think it's complaining that `Users/amin/Documents/cProgram/scipoptsuite-6.0.2/scip/make/make.project` doesn't exist and it doesn't have a rule to produce it.

Comment: should I make this file in this directory?

Comment: I have no idea.  Why did you include a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: I just checked this directory it exist . I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: Is the file there?

Comment: because you have a dollar in front the path that shouldn't be there just use an absolute path

Comment: @UpAndAdam the problem was $. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going about this incorrectly.

First without target the first recipe is the one called, so the `all` target should go first.

second: don't `include` that other file and delete just about everything but the directory variable and the `all` target

you simply need to add to the `LD_FLAGS` variable and the automatic rules will link for you. unless the `scip` project is bringing in a bunch of variables that you need I don't know why you would need to include its make file information here.

Also of note is that the current path you loaded into a variable had an incorrect leading `$` sign in the assignment, and for this to link we will need to make sure its full path to libscip.so ( or libscip.a )

i.e.  `LD_FLAGS+=-L${DIR_containing_libscip.so} -lscip`

you might also need to point to the header/include files:

`CPP_FLAGS+=-I${DIR_before_includes_of_scip}/include` ( if they are included as `<scip/foo>`.  or without the `/include` and going up further if they are to be included just as `<foo>`; this depends upon the projects style. Most projects use the `/include/projname` pattern so as to keep the project effectively in a namespace of its own for include files to avoid collisions.

that should be it assuming everything else is built and in place and there is nothing particularly special about `scip` that I need to know about...

Comment: you mean I should write `all: cmain` at the first line of Makefile?

Comment: could you please help me more? I built make in that directory and it was successful. Now I have a terminal in that directory that was built to use scip. but I have to call this function : SCIPgetGeneratorsSymmetry from scip.  I don't know how

Comment: @sherek_66  Does this help with the SCIPgetGeneratorsSymmetry 
 call? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60052779/2193968

Comment: I mean the first recipe in the file should be all: cmain

other things can first but I wouldn't put other recipes first ( `%.o: %.c` is the recipe you had put before it )

Comment: I still don't know how to use C with skip! I built make file but don't know what is the next step! I am math student not computer Science. I have never programmed before! is there any tutorial to show after building make file how I can compile c file using some functions in scip!

Comment: I used this command : `gcc -o myprog symmetry.c -L/Users/naghmeh/Documents/cProgram -lscip -I/Users/naghmeh/Documents/cProgram`.   but still I get this error: `/usr/local/include/scip/def.h:43:10: fatal error: 'scip/config.h' file not found
#include "scip/config.h"`

Comment: @sherek_66 you need to add a -Iblah where blah is the path that leads to the scip folder that contains config.h

Answer (score 3):

You want to separate two things

1. Building SCIP
2. Building and Linking your program.

## Building SCIP

Usually one would go about and install this library using a package manager on most UNIX-like systems, or do `make install` to copy it into the system. Then, header files etc. will automatically be found.  If you don't want to do that but rather "bundle" SCIP with your program, you usually distribute a copy or link a copy of that version for your program (copy of the code in your sourcetree under eg. "external" or using git submodules, ...). In any case though, you *don't want the path to SCIP to be absolute.* As an example, use this layout:

```
./
-- external/SCIP
-- cmain.c
-- Makefile
```

In the Makefile you can then set SCIPDIR like this for later use:

```
SCIPDIR := "./external/SCIP"
```

First, however, you should understand how to build manually.  For that, you enter "./external/SCIP" and build the library as instructed in the Readme (often by doing something like `./configure && make && make install`).  If you want to automate this, you can do this from **your** main file.  For that you can add a "phony" target (ie. a target that will not exactly create one output but build all dependencies) that we will call `dep`:

```
dep:
        cd $(SCIPDIR); ./configure
        $(MAKE) -C $(SCIPDIR)

.PHONY: dep
```

*(thanks to @UpAndAdam for pointing out that you have to change the CWD before running the configure script)*

For that we recursively call make for our subproject.  We don't want to system-wide install the files, so we just build the library.

## Building your program

We now add two pattern-rules that specify how to build and link C programs. GNU/Make (the one you're using) already has built-in suffix rules s.t. it already by default knows how to build C programs, but suffix rules are hard to deal with and you already use other GNU/Make features, so we can also use pattern-rules that are roughly equivalent and disable the built-in rules:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%: %.o
         $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

.SUFFIXES:
```

A small note here: We compile one object file from one c file by pattern matching. I used the standard variables, CPPFLAGS (C preprocessor, not C++!), CFLAGS (C compiler & Feature flags) and listed all options before the non-option argument `$<` which will hold the (first) dependency listed, eg. "cmain.c". Not all C compilers allow mixing options and arguments.

For linking I do the same, but I list the libraries that we want to link with last. This is important, a classic C compiler will discard any libraries listed there if there wasn't any object earlier in the list that depends on that variable.

Now that we know how to build a generic C program, we actually want to first build SCIP, then your program and link it. For that, we'll create a new PHONY dependency, called "all", that will do exactly that:

```
all: dep cmain

.PHONY: dep all
```

However, if we now execute `make all` it will fail as we haven't yet specified the include path etc. For that, we set the variables that we've used before to the needed values (I guessed the specific path, as I'm on mobile):

```
CPPFLAGS += -I$(SCIPDIR)/include
LDFLAGS += -L$(SCIPDIR)
LDLIBS += -lscip
```

## Putting it all together

Now this should work, more or less. One thing though is, that it's common to have `all` as the default target, that is, the first target listed in the Makefile. So we write:

```
CPPFLAGS += -I$(SCIPDIR)/include
LDFLAGS += -L$(SCIPDIR)
LDLIBS += -lscip

all: dep cmain

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

dep:
    cd $(SCIPDIR); ./configure.sh
    $(MAKE) -C $(SCIPDIR)

.PHONY: dep all
.SUFFIXES:
```

Note: I'm on mobile, so I couldn't test and don't know the exact paths, but this should guide you along. Also my code here used spaces instead of tabs in the Makefile for the same reason. Be sure to replace them.

Comment: you don't need to define any of those pattern rules, those are the implicit definitions already provided by make.  secondly you go to the trouble of defining LDFLAGS but not using it.

the second suffix rule as written is quite dangerous as well.

thirdly you didn't make cmain depend on dec, so this is also very poor.
fourth: the .SUFFIXES clear out should occur BEFORE you define your own suffix rules or you are nullifying everything. 

you can remove the need for dec entirely by marking that as the actual path to the library you want to produce and making that a dependency to cmain

Comment: Also, you absolutely want the path to be absolute... how you get that absolute path is open for question, an excellent way to solve it is to make use of pkg-config... but ultimately you don't want relative paths unless its to libraries that are also fully contained in your project. 

`Absolute Path != Hardcoded Path`; I would agree a hardcoded path isn't what's ideal IF and ONLY IF you are distributing this project outward to others... if its just for you then it is extra work with no return.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I did mention in my answer, that defining the pattern rules is not necessary as we have implicit rules. *however* pattern rules make some things like automatic dependency generation *way* easier. I also do use LDFLAGS. Then, I also do not define any suffix rule, so I don't know which rule is supposed to be dangerous or why. I also don't define any suffix rules, so clearing .SUFFIXES can happen wherever I want.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Making cmain depend on dec is possible, but handling subprojects via make dependencies is tricky in an way. One can, as you said, use an explicit file produced by dep for that, however that introduces other pitfalls, so I left it at that for brevity. In the end, if we'd do it "correctly" at some point we'd end up with our own version of Autotools. Make is a build system, no dependency handler. I also *explicitly* said, that my example was covering the case of the library contained in the project. If the library is properly installed, pkg-config indeed is the way to go.

Comment: Apologies I see LDFLAGS now.  how does your definitions for syntax rules differ from the default ones? dep rule is mildly wrong, the makefiles that configure generates will be places from where you run the command which here is not inside SCIP. I think its good to be explicit especially in examples, and if you moved the suffix clearing fist and possibly reworded your last suffix rule ( so that make foo said no rule for target foo instead of compiling no rule to make foo.o ) this would be an excellent makefile by trimming out unused suffixes making it easier to debug.

Comment: well stated about the pkg-config piece that is a good point since it is contained within.  you are right I confused pattern rules with static suffix rules. I should have not jumped the gun as fast my apologies, humble pie slice taken

Comment: @UpAndAdam The pattern rules are (roughly) equivalent to the built-in ones, I just prefer them, as they are also easier to extend lateron, that's all.  Ah, that's a good point about the configure step, makes it a bit trickier definitely. I'm not sure about what you mean to say about the suffix rules, afaik I'm not using any suffix rules, so I don't see the matter about where to clear them, testing doesn't give different results for me.

Comment: Oh the placement doesn't matter as you pointed out.  I always clear them first in case I or someone else reintroduces a suffix rule later that way it isn't wiped out too. Just a habit no difference like you said. Just like placement of phony.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Ah, I see what you mean, yes, that's definitely a clutter and for many people much bother to debug.  I like implicit rules for simple things and working w/o a Makefile, just running `make test`, but I also always clear them. But I use pattern rules almost exclusively, out of preference anyway and I've heard that *perhaps* they'd be even included in the next POSIX revision. I certainly hope so.

Comment: I'd agree they are much better than the suffix rules. That said for super minimal makefiles I've gotten in habit of just setting flags and doing nothing else except occasional source dependencies. 

I just laugh as I think about arguments of taking out suffix rules because of absurd things that still care about rccs lol